# Twin Primes Python Program

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a Python program that determines whether a given integer input is is a twin prime number or not. If the input number is a twin prime, the program must output true. Otherwise, it must output false.

Please may someone guide me with how this program should be written in Python?

This is what I have done so far. I am stuck at the is_twin_prime function part.

```
def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def is_twin_prime(x):
    if is_prime(x) = True:


N = int(input()) 

for i in range(N):
    p = int(input())
    if is_twin_prime(p):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far, and point out the part that's not working and/or the error you're having.

Comment: Hi there @GreenCloakGuy. Thank you for your response. I have edited my post to include my code that I've written so far. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Do you want to know if N and p are twin_primes of one another?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption, that you are trying to determine if N & p are twin primes of one another, I found several issues with your code as follows:

1. the is_twin_prime function has no False return
2. the is_prime function always starts with 2 and iteratively checks for prime, this is very inefficient.

To provide an answer, I started with the following factoids about twin_primes:

- both numbers must be prime
- abs(n-p) == 2
- n and p must each have a units digit in [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
  To make the function testing for twin primes as efficient as possible, I eliminated any numbers not meeting the last two cases first, and only if necessary did I generate a list of primes.  Also, when generating the primes, I only did it once for the largest number since, once I have the list or the largest both numbers must be in the list.

To make searching for primes more efficient I employed itertools, although this could be done with slightly less efficiency without it's use.

```
import itertools
def erat2():
    D = { }
    yield 2
    for q in itertools.islice(itertools.count(3), 0, None, 2):
        p = D.pop(q, None)
        if p is None:
            D[q*q] = q
            yield q
        else:
            x = p + q
            while x in D or not (x&1):
                x += p
            D[x] = p

def generatePrimes(given_number):
    """
      Returns the prime number <= given_number using
      an adaptive sieve of estraothenes approach
    """ 
    return list(itertools.islice(erat2(), given_number))

def is_twinPrime(n, p):
    accepted_digits = [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
    if abs(n-p) != 2:
        return False
    elif n%10 not in accepted_digits and p%10 not in accepted_digits:
        return False
    else:
        primes = generatePrimes(max(n, p))
        if n in primes and p in primes:
            return True
    return False

N = int(input("Enter first number"))
P = int(input(Enter second number"))
print(istwinPrime(N, P)
```